# why doesn't this jquery html() function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created this very basic example of a jquery html() function but it doesn't work:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var html = "<div>Test</div>";
    $('#TestDiv').html(html);

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="TestDiv" style="height:50px;width:50px;border:1px solid black;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

[View on JSBin](https://jsbin.com/feqataq/edit?html,output)

Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Please place relevant code here. If jsbin goes down your question becomes unanswerable

Comment: To answer your question, you need to put your code in a document.ready handler. See this for more info on jQuery basics: http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/jquery-basics

Comment: You need document ready function. Your code is trying to add text to div that still not exist.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/pirulafajo/1/edit?html,output

Comment: thanks document.ready was the gap

Answer (score 0):

You miss put it on docmuent ready

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function()
{
    var html = "<div>Test</div>";
    $('#TestDiv').html(html);
}
);
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="TestDiv" style="height:50px;width:50px;border:1px solid black;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

put your script after `div` tag
or if you want to keep the script within the `head` tag then you need to included it in $(), like so:[image]

Comment: Please add code in code snippet instead of screenshot.